# SignalR core - Attempting to pass clientId to Hub, can't figure out how to receive

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-core, signalr

Just need to pass the clientId to my query, via the hub but I haven't been able to find a proper example of how to pass and receive a parameter.  I've tried adding the clientId to the ProductCountEventReceiverService but then the Hub stops responding.

My code

```
public interface IEventHub
{
    Task ProductCountSendNoticeEventToClient(string message, string clientId);
}
public class EventHub : Hub<IEventHub>
{
    // method for client to invoke
}
public class ProductCountEventReceiverService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<EventHub> _eventHub;

    private Timer _EventGenTimer;

    public ProductCountEventReceiverService(IHubContext<EventHub> eventHub,  string clientId)
    {
        _eventHub = eventHub;

        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        _EventGenTimer = new Timer(5 * 1000)
        {
            AutoReset = false
        };

        _EventGenTimer.Elapsed += EventGenTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    public void StartReceive()
    {
        _EventGenTimer.Start();
    }

    private void EventGenTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _EventGenTimer.Enabled = false;

        var counts = Business.Product.GetCounts("837");  //Get the ClientID here

        _eventHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(nameof(IEventHub.ProductCountSendNoticeEventToClient),
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(counts)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        _EventGenTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

**My Startup**
//SignalR below
adding blah blah because stack overflow wont let me submit which is very annoying
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddSingleton<ProductCountEventReceiverService>();
    }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<EventHub>("/eventHub");
        });
     }
```

**My Javascript**

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/eventHub?clientId=837")
    .build();

Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', { value: 1 });
var clientId = $("#CurrentClientId").val();

connection.on("ProductCountSendNoticeEventToClient", clientId, function (message) {

    var result = $.parseJSON(message);
    //Do something here
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To send message from server to client

```
 public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
 {
   await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
 }
```

To recieve message from client use `connection.on`

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) { }
```

To send message from client to server use `connection.invoke`

```
connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
```

You can view it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Unfortunatly, when I add ClientId to the above, it no longer finds the hub and so does not fire at all.

Comment: @TimCadieux how did you config your signalr in startup.cs ?

Comment: Added the Startup lines